# How to add extra code into main java method?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add a sentence to all new classes that I create in java. By default Java entry point comes like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

and I want to achive something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in); 
}
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

*Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200*

Comment: Sure.  How you do it depends on your IDE, though, which you haven't mentioned here.

Comment: Java does not create classes.  You are free to create new files however you like.

Comment: This is the entry point, not the constructor. You can change the body of this method, but not the name and parameters.

Comment: @SLaks Well, IDEs like eclipse have a wizard that will generate a class based on a template you configure.  You could set that to have whatever base code and comments you like.

Comment: main() is not a constructor, it's a method that will be executed when running your programme.

Comment: Ok, so how do I add that sentence to the body of the method? @AndrewWilliamson ?

Comment: What IDE/Editor you use, do you have Ediplus, Eclipse or TextPad. You can do Find and Replace.

Comment: @azurefrog: Yes, but then he should ask about the IDE, not about Java.

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109663/eclipse-java-class-templates. It seems like way you're looking for

Comment: You found the exact same one as me :)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse it is possible to edit built-in code templates (the one used by Eclipse e.g. for new class files) and create your own named snippets (for fast access to often-reused templates).

### Code Templates

Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates`, then to `Code > New Java files`. Adapt this or some other template to suit your needs.

### Templates

Usually it's better though to add a smaller template via  `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates` and use it wherever you need. Smaller bricks are more reusable then hardcoded class templates. Those are applied with `<type-beginning-of-template-name + ctrl + space`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create/edit/ any code template you want
For Eclipse go to

1. Window
2. Preferences
3. Java
4. Editor
5. Templates

More here:

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-templates.htm

another here :
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-EditorTemplates.htm