# Automatic repeated java text entry using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse with Java.  I need to define several very similar classes.  It gets tedious typing the same thing automatically each time and wondering whether I could set up a short cut.  I read Eclipse key bindings but it looks like something must already be in a plugin.  This is what I need to type each time

```
 public class SomeClass extends Token {

     WebDriver driver = null;
     WindowStack stack = null;

     @Override 
     public void init() throw InitException {
           super.init();
           driver = TestCont.getWebDriver(); // defined and set elsewhere 
           stack = TestCont.getWindowStack();
     }

     @Override
     public void exec throws ExecException {

     }
 }
```

*SomeClass* is actually some unique name.

I guess I could just keep the text in a file and copy/paste, but it would be nice to create a short cut. I recently saw an online class where someone was using an IDE (I don't know which one it was).  He typed psvm and it automatically changed to

```
 public static void main(String[] argc) {
 }
```

and doing something like new SomeClass(parm1, parm2, parm3).var automatically set to

```
 SomeClass var = new SomeClass(parm1, parm2, parm3);
```

and similarly anything with ".var" at the end would make such a variable.  So I am wondering whether there is a way to do something similar (as above) in Eclipse with Java.

Not sure whether it matters but I have

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_144
```

Comment: I don't know about Eclipse, but NetBeans and IntelliJ have those shortcuts (easy to configure in NetBeans). However if you want to create new classes with the same structure, maybe Eclipse introduced a simpler Template mechanism - or you could try it with code-templates like [in this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109763/896249)

Comment: `psvm` is IntelliJ, in Eclipse it's by default `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define templates in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates

The content assist takes these into account for template completion (the name of the template).

For example, two of the predefined templates are called `sysout` and `syserr`. If you type `sys`, then trigger code completion, it suggests these two templates. Selecting `sysout` results in this code being inserted:

`System.out.println();`

(the template also defines places where other stuff needs to be inserted, where the cursor goes etc. but for your problem that seems like nice-to-have).